# How can I get a display name from the view ID and display ID?

Tags: views, 8

I can load a view with `$view = Views::getView('my_view_id');`, but how do I use that object to load the display_title or say an array containing information including the display name?

Note: This is not to be confused with loading the display's title that might be used when printing the view, as there's a method for that (`getTitle()`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After reading throug the docs (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!src!ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable/8), I tried the following (which worked):

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('your_view_id');
$view->setDisplay('your_display_id');
$displayObj = $view->getDisplay();
//$displayPluginTitle = $displayObj->pluginTitle()->render();
//$displayTitle = $displayObj->getOption('title');
$displayName = $displayObj->display['display_title'];
```

N.B.1: I use the render function on a [TranslatableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!StringTranslation!TranslatableMarkup.php/class/TranslatableMarkup/8) object, this is what the pluginTitle function returns. It could be possible to use other functions there, like, e.g. getUntranslatedString
N.B.2: I misunderstood the OP. :-) Commented out the faulty part of the code, which returns the display plugin's title, and not the display's title as requested.
N.B.3: I misunderstood the OP. AGAIN! :-) Commented out the faulty part of the code, which returns the title of the display, and not the display's name as requested. To my defense, that property is labeled 'Display name' and its name 'display_title' (as was mentioned in the OP).

Screenshot from Views example:

[image]

And a test script that gets the title of the display (with the output):

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Darn I was missing the last line...thanks for that. I'm currently getting the annotated title for my custom display plugin, so perhaps I'm missing some setting in my display plugin.

Comment: Hey there. So, what do you get exactly? What do you mean the annotated title? From the pluginTitle function, I got a TranslatableMarkup object, are you getting something else there?

Comment: I have a custom views display plugin as described here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21display%21DisplayPluginInterface.php/group/views_display_plugins/8.  It is annotated with @ViewsDisplay, which includes a title. That title is what I am getting back with the last line.

Comment: Your own implementation I reckon. Have you implemented/overriden the pluginTitle function then?

Comment: Correct it's a custom implementation, but no I did not implement/override pluginTitle()

Comment: I tried this for a view with two block displays, and indeed I got the annotation title "Block" instead of the custom display titles provided to each block display.

Comment: Got it! Updating my answer!

Comment: Hmm now I'm getting an empty string. Again tried it with my custom display type and the blocks displays.

Comment: Note I am indeed getting a valid Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Block object from `$displayObj = $view->getDisplay();` that includes the object Drupal\webprofiler\Views\TraceableViewExecutable, which in turn includes the display titles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38169/discussion-between-stefanos-petrakis-and-webdrips).

Answer (score 0):

The following code depends on the ctools_views module.

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('your_view_id');
$view->setDisplay('your_display_id');
$displayObj = $view->getDisplay();
$displayName = $displayObj->display['display_title'];
```

To get the display title only requires the following code.

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('your_view_id');
$view->setDisplay('your_display_id');
$displayName = $view->getTitle();
```